# Getting an element from a position in an array in main method

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out the position of the smallest variable and the actual smallest variable at the position. I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be like Array[pos], but I cannot get it to recognize "pos" as a variable in the main method.

```
public static int Findsmallest(int[]A)
{
    int smallest = A[0];

    int pos = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] < smallest) 
        {
            smallest = A[i];
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    return pos;

}

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        int [] C = new int[100];
        loadArray (C);
        printArray (C);
        System.out.println("The average is " + avg(C));
        System.out.println(search(C,2));
        System.out.println(Findsmallest(C) + C[pos]);
        System.out.println(Findlargest(C));

    }
```

Comment: Yes, pos is the variable

Comment: Call FindSmallest(), and store the result in a variable. Then use that variable. Note that Java methods conventionally start with a lowercase character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FindSmallest()` `method` already `return` the smallest's position: So just print out its value like:

```java
System.out.println( "Smallest Position: " +  Findsmallest (C));
```

To also print out the smallest value at that position?

```java
System.out.println( "Smallest : " + C[  Findsmallest (C)] );
```

Comment: System.out.println( "Smallest : " + C[  Findsmallest (C)] ); was what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Connor there's no reason to call the method twice. Call it once, and store the result in a variable. Then use that variable.

Answer (score 1):

`pos` isn't defined in `main`; fortunately, the value you want is being returned by the call to `Findsmallest`.

Comment: Also, doing `Findsmallest(C) + C[pos]` would do the sum of the two integers, which won't produce a meaningful output. I presume the attempt was to print two integers.

Comment: That get's me the position of the smallest value, but how do I also print out the smallest value at that position?

Comment: @Connor , first assign the position to a variable in the `main` method, then print the variable and `pos[variable]`.